# Android Assets folder does not get recognized

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am doing a Xamarin Forms project with iOS and Android, and I am trying to retrieve a txt file from the assets folder for Android and from the Resources folder in iOS. It works for iOS but it doesn't work for Android. To be exact, in the Android project, the path for my text file is "Assets/versions/latestVersion.txt"

I have this Base URL for Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.Android
{
    public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in my code, I have:

```
string versioningFile = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
string path = Path.Combine(versioningFile, "versions/latestVersion.txt");

string file = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

My IBaseUrl is

```
public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
```

It doesn't recognize the path, the error states "Could not find a part of the path /file:/android_asset/versions/latestVersion.txt".

What is the problem ? The path is clearly what i want it to be.

Comment: assets are not files - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: What do you mean ? The android_asset is just my directory to get my files

Comment: is the Build Action "Android Asset" - those are an Android specific resource type, read the docs.  If you are just including them in a folder named "Assets" and they are not actually Android assets, what is their Build Action?  Even then, the "path" you are using with `File.Open` is not a path, it is a url

Comment: I followed this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows
because I also have to read an html file, so i put them both at the same place

Comment: I'd suggest that you read it again, because it is using `AssetManager` to read the Android assets

Comment: It says it "can" also be accessed through the current Android context, so I thought there were multiple options.

Comment: they are passing `base_url` to the WebView, which can handle urls.  You are trying to use it with `File.ReadAllText` which expects a path, not a url

Answer (score 0):

About [Assete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows#reading-assets),it's read using an `AssetManager`.

You could also use [File System Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-file-system-helpers) of **Xamarin.Essentials**.

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(fileName))
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
    var fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
}
```

**Note**: Add any file into the `Assets` folder in the Android project and mark the `Build Action` as `AndroidAsset`